# MySql count from other table as join and add to every row of results

Tags: mysql, join, count

Got a small MySql problem I was hoping someone could take a look at.

Current Sql:

```
SELECT IFNULL(ua.total, 0) applications, 
       users_applications.job_id as job_id, 
       users.* 
FROM users_applications 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
             on (users_applications.user_id = users.id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
                           SELECT COUNT(*) total, job_id, id 
                           FROM users_applications
                           GROUP BY job_id ) AS ua 
                  ON (users_applications.id = ua.id)
```

Which is great and it's returning something like:

```
applications  |  job_id  |  user_id  |
-------------------------------
3     |   1001    |   1001  |
0     |   1001    |   1002  |
0     |   1001    |   1003  |
1     |   1003    |   1004  |
1     |   1003    |   1005  |
0     |   1004    |   1006  |
```

Although it is counting the number of applications for that job it's only doing it for the first row, I'd like it to appear in every row instead of just a 0 for subsequent rows as it is  at the moment.

Many thanks

Comment: so that would mean all records of job_id has `3 applications`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT  c.totalCount,
        a.job_id,
        a.user_id
FROM    users_applications a
            LEFT JOIN users b
                ON a.user_ID = b.ID
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT job_ID, count(*) totalCount
                    FROM user_applications
                    GROUP BY job_ID
                ) c on a.job_ID = c.jobID
```

Comment: Whoo!! Thank you very much. So basically I join it on the job_id not the user id.